# TikZ — joining a plot and a line segment

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, join

Is there a way to join a plot and a line segment in TikZ?

Here is a shape I'm trying to draw:

[image: a complex shape]

I almost happy with the result, but there is a gap between the plotted segment and the rest of the drawing:

[image: the gap]

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=0.5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm]
    \def\r{10.5}
    \def\w{18}  

    \coordinate (a) at ({\r*cos(180-\w)}, {\r*sin(180-\w)});
    \coordinate (b) at ({\r*cos(\w)}, {\r*sin(\w)});

    \draw[domain=\w:{180-\w}, variable=\x, samples=250] 
        (a) to[out=270, in=180] 
        (-8, 1.25) --
        (-8, 0.75) -- 
        (-1, 0.75) -- 
        (-1, 8) to[out=20, in=250] 
        (0, 9) to[out=290, in=160] 
        (1, 8) -- 
        (1, 0.75) -- 
        (8, 0.75) -- 
        (8, 1.25) to[out=0, in=270] 
        (b) plot ({\r*cos(\x)}, {\r*sin(\x)}) -- (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The percusse's solution works well:

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=0.5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm]
    \def\r{10.5}
    \def\w{18}  

    \coordinate (b) at ({\r*cos(180-\w)}, {\r*sin(180-\w)});
    \coordinate (a) at ({\r*cos(\w)}, {\r*sin(\w)});
    \coordinate (c) at ({\r*cos(-\w)}, {\r*sin(-\w)});
    \coordinate (d) at ({\r*cos(-180+\w)}, {\r*sin(-180+\w)});

    \pgfmathsetmacro\t{90-\w}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\z{90+\w}

    \draw[line width=0.2mm, domain={180-\w}:\w, variable=\x, samples=250]  plot ({\r*cos(\x)}, {\r*sin(\x)}) -- 
        (a) to[out=-\t, in=0] 
        (8, 1.25) --
        (8, 0.75) -- 
        (1, 0.75) -- 
        (1, 8) to[out=160, in=290] 
        (0, 9) to[out=250, in=20]
        (-1, 8) --
        (-1, 0.75) -- 
        (-8, 0.75) -- 
        (-8, 1.25) to[out=180, in=-\z] 
        (b) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I've adjusted the angles and plotted the round segment first. There is no gap even at 6400%:

[image: no gap solution]

If you wonder, why do I need a shape like this, it's a part of the Artobolevskii's tool for drawing of logarithmic spirals:

[image: Artobolevskii's drawing tool]

Comment: change the order, start with the plot and finish on b with `--cycle` ?

Comment: Put there a point (disk) to cover the hole.

Comment: @percusse --cycle is good for closed shapes, but I have some unclosed too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `--cycle` does not work for you, one option would be to adjust the `out` and `in` angle so that the lines are at the same angle as what they are connecting to. This slightly changes the shape, so if that is not required to be that precise you can get (at 6400% zoom on the left hand side):

[image]

### Notes:

- On the left hand side I changed `270` to `250`, but on the right hand side the required change was from `270` to `288`.  Not sure why the right hand side required a slightly different angle delta. For more precision you could compute the actual angle, but trial and error works pretty well.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=0.5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm, join=cap]
    \def\r{10.5}
    \def\w{18}  

    \coordinate (a) at ({\r*cos(180-\w)}, {\r*sin(180-\w)});
    \coordinate (b) at ({\r*cos(\w)}, {\r*sin(\w)});

    \draw[domain=\w:{180-\w}, variable=\x, samples=250] 
        (a) to[out=250, in=180] %% <--- Adjusted out angle here
        (-8, 1.25) --
        (-8, 0.75) -- 
        (-1, 0.75) -- 
        (-1, 8) to[out=20, in=250] 
        (0, 9) to[out=290, in=160] 
        (1, 8) -- 
        (1, 0.75) -- 
        (8, 0.75) -- 
        (8, 1.25) to[out=0, in=288] <--- Adjusted in angle here
        (b) plot ({\r*cos(\x)}, {\r*sin(\x)}) -- (a)
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Adjusting the angle will work for sure. I tried to avoid it too, but probably it's the best solution. Thanks.